# What do you recommend to see if my data fits Minimum Extreme Value distribution?

Tags: distributions, p-value, fitting, extreme-value

I have the following data:

```
15.8 16.1 16.5 16.5 16.6 16.8 17.0 18.0 18.7 18.7 18.9 19.0 19.3 21.0 22.8
22.9 23.0 23.0 23.2 23.3 23.4 23.4 23.9 24.0 24.2 24.5 25.5 25.5 25.8 26.4
27.3 27.7 27.8 28.6 29.4 30.3 30.6 31.2 31.2 32.1 32.4 32.8 33.7 34.2 34.9
35.0 35.1 35.1 35.3 35.4
```

And I need to see if that fits with the Minimum Extreme Value distribution.

I've found the parameters $\beta= 4.8747, \mu = 28.2897$. Besides, I've tried to use the KS test but I'm not sure if I do it well (R studio says me that ties are not allowed)

What do you recommend to see if my data fits with the Extreme Value distribution and get a p-value?. Thanks